# Fraction Sum Series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic, fractions

This question was asked in (selection) IMO for 8th graders.

$1/2 + 1/6 + 1/12+ 1/20 + 1/30 + 1/42 +1/56 + 1/72 + 1/90 + 1/110 +1/132$

I have noticed that it can be written as $1/(1*2) + 1/(2*3) +1/(3*4) + 1/(4*5).... +1/(11*12)$

However I don't know how to continue..

Comment: Parentheses, please.  $1/1*2$ can be read as $(1/1)*2$ which is clearly not what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Your sum can be written in the following form:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{11} \dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

Apply partial fraction decomposition to $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ to write it in the form $\frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{n+1}$ and see what happens as you simplify.

> The series should telescope.  I.e. adjacent terms will cancel with one another, leaving you with only the first and last terms not cancelled.  You have $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$.  The series then looks like $\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-\cdots-\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{12}$

Answer (score 3):

Then note that $\frac 1{1\cdot 2}$ = $\frac 11 - \frac 12$ and the sum telescopes.