# Need a hint to solve example...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I can solve this type of problem first time so need hint what can I do and where I get such more problem.

The Value of $$100\left[\frac{1}{(1)(2)}+\frac{1}{(2)(3)}+ \frac{1}{(3)(4)}+\ldots+\frac{1}{(99)(100)}\right]$$

Comment: Check out what happens when you combine $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: okay. I get $ \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Comment: Yes, exactly. Now write down an "=" sign and put your answer on the left, and mine on the right. Also, check out all the denominators of the series in your question. Anything you notice?

Comment: Ah ,you see it :)

Comment: I had asked a very similar question and received satisfactory answers http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652786/fraction-sum-series