# Show with reccurence that 1/(1*2) + 1/(2*3) + ... + 1/n(n+1) = n/(n+1)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The theory presented to me didn't make me understand how to do this kind of problem. I need help.
Thanks you!

Comment: Notice that $\frac{1}{2\cdot 3} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255306/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1652789/42969.

Answer (score 0):

It's a telescoping sum:

$$\frac1{1\times2}+\frac1{2\times3}+\cdots+\frac1{n(n+1)}$$

$$=\left(\frac11-\frac12\right)+\left(\frac12-\frac13\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)$$

$$=1-\frac1{n+1}=\dfrac n{n+1}$$